# Where can I look for backup script?

Tags: linux, windows, backup, fedora

I want find out where the backup script of a Fedora 8 server is. I haven't found it so far ( my Linux knowledge is very spare). I looked with `crontab -l` and I only can find a tempdelete.pl. Than I looked into `/etc/cron.daily` and I can see

- 000-delay.cron
- logrotate
- mlocate.cron
- rpm
- tmpwatch
- 0anacron
- cups
- makewhatis.cron
- prelink
- tetex.con

Nothing which looks like a backup script if taken the name. Nothing in the `/etc/cron.hourly` directory and `etc/cron.weekly` looks similar.

The backup script includes backup from Windows and Linux machines (about 5 machines). I also saw that there is a separate backup user. It came to my mind that the backups are started from the other machines, not from the machine which holds the backup. I also looked under `/mnt` and there are three entries, but all are empty.

I looked on one Windows machine and didn't found something in the task planner. Also the other backup software which is on this machine doesn't make this backup.

How can I find out how the backup mechanism is working? Hope someone can help me out.

**@Zoredache**:
Yes, I inherited it from my precursor. I think it is a script, because no backup system was mentioned. On one Windows machine there is `CA ARCserve Backup Manager`, but it only makes backup on tapes. My precursor told me that it exists and one time I looked on it and the disk space is now empty. Therefore I want to find out how the backup looks like. I don't really know if it is running, I only saw that the diskspace is empty and thats why I think it is running. I add an excerpt of `/var/log`, but I don't know if it is logged.

```
anaconda.log
anaconda.syslog
anaconda.xlog
audit
bittorrent
boot.log
boot.log-20120115
boot.log-20120122
boot.log-20120129
boot.log-20120205
btmp
btmp-20120201
cron
cron-20120115
cron-20120122
cron-20120129
cron-20120205
cups
dmesg
faillog
gdm
httpd
lastlog
mail
maillog
maillog-20120115
maillog-20120122
maillog-20120129
maillog-20120205
messages
messages-20120115
messages-20120122
messages-20120129
messages-20120205
ntpstats
ppp
prelink
proftpd
rpmpkgs
rpmpkgs-20120115
rpmpkgs-20120122
rpmpkgs-20120129
rpmpkgs-20120205
samba
secure
secure-20120115
secure-20120122
secure-20120129
secure-20120205
setroubleshoot
spooler
spooler-20120115
spooler-20120122
spooler-20120129
spooler-20120205
tallylog
vbox
wtmp
wtmp-20120201
xferlog
Xorg.0.log
Xorg.0.log.old
yum.log
```

In which log file should I look? In `cron` I see this

```
Feb  9 19:01:01 backup CROND[19717]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: So did you inherit a box from someone else?  Do you know the name of the backup system?  How do you know it exists?  How do you know it is running?  If you see it writing logs or reports somewhere, then can you post an example line?

Comment: @Zoredache: I updated my question.

Comment: `ls /var/spool/cron` should show if there are crontabs for other users. Do `crontab -l -u USER` to output these.

Comment: there is also `/etc/cron.d` (yes, there are a dozen and one places cron jobs can be stored).

Answer (score 1):

The backup process could be performed via a daemon process.  Check to see if a ARCserv unix process is running or is configured in init (ie: `ls /etc/init.d/`)